# jquery when clicked outside the div close the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What actually I get is given in: http://jsfiddle.net/y9uwY/7/

What I want:

1. if user click on black area then nothin should happen
2. clicked outside the black area must be closed

Comment: can u tell y is it not working..

Comment: @sem it kind of *is*...At least he has tried, and has shown his code, which is more than many questions you see here.

Comment: Could you put it all together in a JSFiddle so we can see it better ? I tried but something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stop the event bubbling up to body. Here is the corrected code http://jsfiddle.net/y9uwY/8/

For Reference and Further Reading: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 1):

try this fiddle, your `body` tag will only ever be the size of the main `.select_roles` element, so setting the widths and heights to 100% gives you a clickable area for the hide (this works in msot browsers, to allow for a little more, might be worth adding some padding as well). This simply sets the `.select_roles` to `display:none;` but starts with the class of `.active` to make it `display:block;` once you click outside of the area we remove the `.active` class.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9uwY/3/

Answer (score 1):

try the fiddle now
http://jsfiddle.net/y9uwY/9/

```
$('.select_roles').click(function (e){
    e.stopPropagation();
                 if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                 }
                 });

            $('body').click(function (){
                 if($('.select_roles').hasClass('active')){
                     $('.select_roles').removeClass('active');
                 }
            });
```